# PHP CURL Error 7 failed to connect to host

Tags: php, curl

I have a peculiar problem i am facing with Php CURL .

I am trying to call a web service running on a windows machine within the same network via a php script running on a centos workstation. I am using CURL. The problem is that i can access the URL with the browser and it works perfectly. BUt when i try to use the php script it gives an error code 7 .

HOwever if i try a local ip address and google in the php script it works with no issues. What could be the issue? I have been trying to get me head around this issue for the past few hours but i am not able to sort it.

I would also like to add, when i use crl via the terminal i get a proper reply. HTTP 200OK

Help Required :)

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
   CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13',
   CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
   CURLOPT_PORT => 9710,          
   CURLOPT_URL => 'http://192.168.100.4:9710/http/send-message?message='.$message
));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo "<br>Error Code : " .curl_errno($curl);
```

Comment: Please add your php code to the question.

Comment: Of course you try in a browser from the CentOS machine, not Windows?

Comment: I did try on a centos machine not windows ring0

Answer (score 1):

There was selinux enabled on the Centos Machine, and that was causing the problem. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: it happens on fedora too

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
   CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,          
   CURLOPT_URL => 'http://192.168.100.4:9710/http/send-message?message='.$message
));

if(curl_exec($curl) === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo 'Success!';
}
```

One thing I noticed was that you were trying to access the port twice.

Comment: I tried that but it dint not work out. I was trying all the different options to make it work but can't figure out what is blocking or avoiding the request, do I have to chande anything in the header or options?