# Getting the error message "Failed to connect to live.stellar.org port 9002" - PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

I've got this message .

> Failed to connect to live.stellar.org port 9002: Connection timed out

My code is , please help me.

```
$fields = array(
    'method' => 'account_tx',
    'params' => array(
        array(
        'account' => 'gPP3hmC86rA8aJiCwRLXRLd9NxGnL2qSwG',
        'limit' => '20'
        )
        )
);

$data = json_encode($fields);
$response = curl_post($data);

function curl_post($fields)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://live.stellar.org:9002");
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 9002);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec ($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close ($ch); 
    return $response;
}
```

This is API code from Stellar :

```
curl -X POST https://live.stellar.org:9002 -d '
{
  "method": "account_tx",
  "params": [
    {
      "account": "gPP3hmC86rA8aJiCwRLXRLd9NxGnL2qSwG",
      "limit": 4
    }
  ]
}'
```

Comment: well the error seems clear to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything is right.

So, possibilities are:

1. Maybe your server IP is banned on that site;
2. Maybe a firewall is preventing you to reach this host/port;
3. Maybe you need to extend the timeout.

Try this code on another host or run it locally to be sure.

Comment: I saw in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418312/php-curl-error-7-failed-to-connect-to-host . They said "There was selinux enabled on the Centos Machine, and that was causing the problem." . How can i fix it ?